# I want to use java 7 but the computer acts like it is not installed?

Tags: 12.04

i installed Java 7 but when i try to open a application in terminal it says i am using Java 6

the only thing i can really open is minecraft

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and start

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Select Java 7. That's all.

*Example*

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1095      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1085      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1091      manual mode
  5            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1095      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

---

Check with

`java -version` and you should see something loke this

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```